# Proving sigma-algebras equality

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

I'm not sure if my proof of the following statement is correct.

> Let $\tau : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a non-negative random variable, defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$. We define the jump process associated with the random variable $\tau$ by setting $H_t=\mathbb{1}_{ \{ \tau \leq t \} }$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$. We set $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}= \sigma ( H_u : u \in \mathbb{R}_+ )$. Then we have
>   $$\mathcal{H}_{\infty} = \sigma(\tau).$$

This is my attempt of proving the above statement:

> 1st Part: To prove that $\mathcal{H}_{\infty} \subseteq \sigma(\tau)$. Since $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}=\sigma ( \{\tau \leq u \} : u \in \mathbb{R}_+ )$, it would be enough to prove that for an arbitrary $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \sigma(\tau)$. But that is obvious, since
>   $$\{ \tau \leq t \} = \{ \omega: \tau (\omega) \in \left[ 0,t \right]\} = \tau^{-1}(\left[0,t\right])\in\sigma(\tau).$$
>
> 2nd Part: To prove $\sigma(\tau) \subseteq \mathcal{H}_{\infty}$, i.e. to prove that for every $X \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+})$, $\tau^{-1}(X) \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty}$. For the convenience, here we can use the fact that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)=\sigma(\left[ 0,u \right]: u \in \mathbb{R}_+ )$. It is obvious that for an arbitrary $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$, we have $ \tau^{-1}(\left[ 0,t \right]) \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty} $.
>
> Next, we have to prove that from the assumption that for some $X \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+})$, $\tau^{-1}(X) \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty}$, it follows that $\tau^{-1}(X^C)\in \mathcal{H}_{\infty} $. That is also ok since by the assumption we have
>   $$\tau^{-1}(X) = \{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \in X \} \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty},$$
>   and it follows (using \sigma-algebra properties) that
>   $$\left( \tau^{-1} (X) \right)^C=\{ \omega: \tau (\omega) \in X^C \}\in \mathcal{H}_{\infty}. $$
>
> Finally, we have to prove that if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+})$ s.t. $\tau^{-1}(X_i) \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty} \ \forall i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, it follows that $\tau^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{i=1, \dots, n} X_i \right) \in\mathcal{H}_{\infty}$. Here we can again use one of the $\sigma$-algebras properties, precisely the one which states that the countable union of the elements of a $\sigma$-algebra is again in the same $\sigma$-algebra, thus we have
>   $$\tau^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{i=1, \dots, n} X_i \right) = \{ \omega: \tau (\omega) \in \bigcup_{i=1, \dots, n} X_i \} =\bigcup_{i=1, \dots, n} \{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \in X_i \} \in \mathcal{H}_{\infty}.$$

I appreciate any insights on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you are convinced that $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}=\sigma ( \{\tau \leq u \} : u \in \mathbb{R}_+ )$, then there is no problem, since $\sigma ( \{\tau \leq u \} : u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ) = \sigma(\tau)$.